# Set an outlet for a UICollectionView inside a UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I would like to put a collection view inside a table cell that scrolls horizontally. I have set the datasource and delegate of the collection view to be the the same as the Table View Controller. When I drag from the collection view to the tableviewcontroller it throws an error that the outlet from the collection view cannot be connected to the table view controller and that outlets cannot be connected to repeating content.

A portion of my code:

```
class MyTableViewController: UITableViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var testCollectionView: UICollectionView!

//Table View methods...
//CollectionView Delegate methods...

}
```

Comment: This is logically wrong  thing to do. You need to make your cell class itself as the datasource and delegate and not the table view controller that hosts the cells.  You will need to rely on the cell's model to derive data for you collection view that is within cell.

Comment: @Shripada Thank you. That fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the outlet has to be put in the cell itself not in the controller.

And when the cellForRowAtIndexPath gets called in your view controller, there you need to access the cell's collectionview and set the delegates and datasource as self there.

In that way, you viewController will be the delegate and dataSource of the collectionview created in the custom cell for the tableView in your view Controller.